# Swift2で絵文字キーボードを作って、非表示ボタンで非表示にしたいがどうしたらいいか？

Tags: swift

Swift2でキーボードを作った場合、どうしたらキーボードを非表示にできますか？

キーボードに非表示ボタン作って、それを押下して、キーボードを隠したいのです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout() 

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard") 
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) 


    bunPrint() 
    btnTitle1() 
    fFastBoot = false 

}

・・・

func btnDown56(sender: UIButton){
    fDub = false
    self.button56.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let proxy = textDocumentProxy
    proxy.insertText("")
    SiftCange()
}
func btnUp56(sender: UIButton){
    self.button56.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIInputViewController`を継承したカスタムキーボード側から閉じたいということであれば、`dismissKeyboard()`を呼ぶだけです。

[UIInputViewControllerのリファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/)の冒頭に書いてあります。

---

補足。通常のアプリケーションからキーボードを閉じる場合は`resignFirstResponder()`を使いますが、カスタムキーボードでは違う操作になります。

これがなぜかというと、ファーストレスポンダ（現在入力対象となっている`UITextView`など）を管理しているのが、アプリケーションのキーウインドウとなっている`UIWindow`だからです。

エクステンションのキーボードは、ホストアプリケーションへ直接アクセスすることはできないので、ファーストレスポンダへメッセージを送ることができないのです。表示される領域も`UITextEffectWindow`という通常のビュー階層が属しているのとは別のウインドウとなっています。

Comment: 見落としていました。ありがとうございます。